# Get JSOUP data from website that loads values after page is fully loaded

Tags: java, android, jsoup

[image: 107.7 is injected after load]

http://www.racv.com.au/wps/wcm/connect/racv/internet/primary/my+car/fuel/petrol+prices/search+for+petrol+prices+around+melbourne

Trying to get the petrol price data from here. Inspect the price element and reload the page - you'll see it get put in there after the fact

I'm trying to fetch fuel price data.

The 107.7  is there when the page is loaded, but when you try and use JSOUP, and get the html, it doesn't show up.

Turns out they wait for the page to load or something, and then inject the value into the page a bit later

Whats a valid work around for this? Is there a way to load the full page and wait for those values to by injected, then fossick through the HTML?

THanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Whats a valid work around for this? Is there a way to load the full page and wait for those values to by injected, then fossick through the HTML?

It seems this page is loaded with some javascript. Use [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) or [ui4j](https://github.com/ui4j/ui4j) in this case.